# ToolbarManager: Why separators are not displayed?

Tags: java, swt, action, toolbar, separator

This is my code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = new ToolBar(this, SWT.NONE);
toolbar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
ToolbarManager toolbarManager = new ToolBarManager(toolbar);
//... create an action...
toolbarManager.add(toolbarAction);
toolbarManager.add(new Separator());
//... create an action...
toolbarManager.add(toolbarAction);
//... create an action...
toolbarManager.add(toolbarAction);
//... create an action...
toolbarManager.add(toolbarAction);
toolbarManager.add(new Separator());
toolbarManager.update(false);
```

Why in the resulting toolbar only the actions are desplayed and not the separators?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or at least post a link to one?

Comment: Put the working code in you question.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using SWT.FLAT | SWT.HORIZONTAL instead of SWT.NONE

-Sumit Thokal